# Why does .mro() on a metaclass have a different signature? `descriptor 'mro' of 'type' object needs an argument`

Tags: python, metaclass, method-resolution-order

On most types/classes in Python, I can call `.mro()` without arguments.  But not on `type` and its descendants:

```
In [32]: type(4).mro()
Out[32]: [int, object]

In [33]: type(type(4)).mro()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-48a6f7fcd2fe> in <module>()
----> 1 type(type(4)).mro()

TypeError: descriptor 'mro' of 'type' object needs an argument
```

It appears I can get what I want with `type(type(4)).mro(type(4))`, but why can't I call `mro()` directly as I do elsewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `mro` is a method of the metaclass and it needs an instance -- i.e. a class --, pretty much like given an ordinary class `C` and a method `m` you can call `C.m(inst)` or `inst.m()`, but you can't call `C.m()`, as it expects the `self` argument.

If you want to call `mro` with a metaclass or `type` itself, you can use `type.mro(type)`.

Comment: Hmm, I see.  But `type` is also an instance of `type`...!  Confusing.

Comment: Just like `object` and `type` are instances of each other. It's not like the interpreter uses `type` to create `type` or `object`. They are both "elementary" classes hardcoded in the interpreter.

Comment: I suppose another confusion was that I believed `mro` to be a classmethod because I called it on the class.

Comment: It's a method of the metaclass, not a classmethod. They can both be called from the class, but they're not quite the same thing.

Comment: Right, which explains the origin of my confusion.

Comment: The Python documentation index [calls `mro` a classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3.6/genindex-M.html)...

Comment: @gerrit It's a class method defined in the metaclass, not a class method injected into the class with the @classmethod() decorator.